# Calling another Action Helper from another action Helper in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, helper

Is it possible to call another action helper from another action helper. Actually I have created an action helper which preform some layout related stuff using preDispatch hook. Now I want to call [ajaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) within my first action helper's preDispatch method. any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker to fetch other helpers.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend from Zend's abstract class you can use actionController variable to access controller and use sth. like $this->_actionController->layout(); (for layout action helper)